# Is there a way of programatically extracting terms (length of contract) from free text

Tags: python, regex, nltk, spacy, text-extraction

I want to extract contract length from text to term in months. Free text fields range from:

```
"2 x 5 year terms",
"3 further  x 4 years",
"two(2) further terms of five(5) years each",
"Two (2) Years + Two (2) Years + Two (2) Years",
"1 years + 1 years + 1 years" ,
"2 x 3 years",
"1 year and 6 months",
"
```

I'd like the output to be:

```
120 months,
144 months,
120 months,
72 months, 
36 months
72 months
18 months
```

```
import re

def calculate_duration(term):
    term = term.lower()

    # Handle "x year terms" pattern
    match = re.match(r'(\d+) x (\d+) year terms?', term)
    if match:
        return int(match.group(1)) * int(match.group(2)) * 12
    
    # Handle "FURTHER TERMS OF x YEARS EACH" pattern
    match = re.match(r'further terms of (\d+) years each', term)
    if match:
        return int(match.group(1)) * 12


    # Handle "FURTHER TERMS OF x YEARS EACH" pattern
    match = re.match(r'further terms of (\d+) years each', term)
    if match:
        return int(match.group(1)) * 12
    
    # Handle "FURTHER TERMS OF x YEARS EACH" pattern
    match = re.match(r'further terms of ((?:\d+\s?\(\w+\)\s?)?(\d+)) years each', term)
    if match:
        return int(match.group(2)) * 12

    # Handle "x years + x years + x years" pattern
    match = re.match(r'(\d+) years(\s?\+\s?\d+ years)+', term)
    if match:
        return sum(int(match.group(1)) for group in match.groups()) * 12

    # Handle other patterns or simple year counts
    match = re.match(r'(\d+) years?', term)
    if match:
        return int(match.group(1)) * 12

    # Handle other cases or unknown patterns
    return None

# Example usage
terms = [
    "2 x 5 year terms",
    "3 further x 4 YEAR terms",
    "Two (2) Years + Two (2) Years + Two (2) Years",
    "1 years + 1 years + 1 years" ,
    "2 x 3 years"
]

for term in terms:
    duration = calculate_duration(term)
    print(f"{term}: {duration} months")
```

Comment: What is your actual question?  If this code isn't doing what you want, then you need to **explain the problem**.

Comment: In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Rules-based extraction is not ideal for this type of problem in all honesty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"... I want to extract contract length from text to term in months. ..."*

Utilize the *[eval](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)* *built-in function*.

Traverse the the text, appending the according values; numbers and operators.
When a *"year"* value is encountering, adjust the previous value accordingly; multiply by *12*.

From here, produce a mathematical expression, by concatenating the values.

Here is an example.

```py
import re

def parse(s: str):
    e = []
    for i, x in enumerate(s.split()):
        if any([c.isdigit() for c in x]):
            e.append(int(re.sub(r'\D', '', x)))
        elif 'year' in x.lower(): e[-1] *= 12
        elif x in ['x', 'of']: e.append('*')
        elif x in ['+', 'and']: e.append('+')
    return e

text = ['2 x 5 year terms',
        '3 further x 4 years',
        'two(2) further terms of five(5) years each',
        'Two (2) Years + Two (2) Years + Two (2) Years',
        '1 years + 1 years + 1 years',
        '2 x 3 years',
        '1 year and 6 months']
for string in text:
    exp = ' '.join(map(str, parse(string)))
    print(exp, '=', eval(exp))
```

Output

```
2 * 60 = 120
3 * 48 = 144
2 * 60 = 120
24 + 24 + 24 = 72
12 + 12 + 12 = 36
2 * 36 = 72
12 + 6 = 18
```

---

Edit

A similar approach would be to remove any non-associative values, i.e., keeping only *"years"*, *"of"*, *"and"*, digits, and the characters, *'x'*, and *'+'*.

```py
import re

a = re.compile(r'(?i)\b(?!(?:years?)|of|and|\d|x|\+)\w+|[()]')
b = re.compile(r'(?<!\S)[ \t]+| +$')

def parse(s: str):
    global a, b
    s = a.sub('', s).lower()
    s = b.sub('', s).replace('s', '')
    e = []
    for i, x in enumerate(s.split()):
        if x.isdigit(): e.append(int(x))
        elif x == 'year': e[-1] *= 12
        elif x in ['x', 'of']: e.append('*')
        elif x in ['+', 'and']: e.append('+')
    return ' '.join(map(str, e))

text = ['2 x 5 year terms',
        '3 further x 4 years',
        'two(2) further terms of five(5) years each',
        'Two (2) Years + Two (2) Years + Two (2) Years',
        '1 years + 1 years + 1 years',
        '2 x 3 years',
        '1 year and 6 months']
for string in text:
    exp = parse(string)
    print(exp, '=', eval(exp))
```